# Necessary programming languages for a quiz site

Tags: php, mysql

this question is coming from a complete noob in programming. So, my aim is to study lots of things to create in the end from scratch a site similar to Quizfarm. That is, I need to develop a system that will allow me to create new quizes from scratch, post them in the necessary categories (for example fun quizes, serious quizes, quizes for children, for grown ups, for anything).

Visitors will be allowed to login, to have their own profile page (with the ability to upload an avatar image) and can see which quizes they took and how they scored. The site will feature a ranking system for each quiz independently, ranking for each category and total ranking (for example). In addition, it needs to have the ability that members can win small prizes (not monetary prizes, but just simple icons that will show in their profile, like achievements).

I know, my question is too vague possibly, and the whole project very large. I suppose that programming languages like php and MySQL are necessary.  Which other languages should I go for (except of html/css of course for the design part)? 
Thanks for your time and I will appreciate any answer.

Comment: `I know, my question is too vague possibly` -- then why ask?  I don't think we can tell you what to learn. It depends on your requirements. Learn what you need to get the job done.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about suggesting programming languages and not related to programming

Comment: You can use any programming language you like

Comment: Amal, I am asking to learn from experienced people, it is as if asking someone a direction and they point you to somewhere. And as the question is about programming, is it really so much off topic Mr Alien?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated your question is very broad and you can use any programming language that you like. From experience however I would highly recommend that you use PHP.

It's relatively easy to learn, very adaptable and it doesn't mind if you make mistakes.

So for the front end HTML and CSS, for the actual website PHP, and SQL for the database

You can also use JavaScript or jQuery. It will definitely be needed down the track, but use it sparingly until you get a good web application working first. You'll mainly need it to enhance user interactivity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Would the down voter mind to explain?

Comment: I suspect the downvote is for answering a question that was well off-topic. Don't worry about it though, once you've spent a bit of time here you'll get a feel for what questions aren't a good fit.

Comment: Thanks guys, I know my question was vague, I just thought that this site would provide me with some general guidelines. Some heavy learning to do now.

Answer (score -1):

- HTML
- CSS
- PHP
- Mysql
- Javascript with jQuery lib

Those are the basics that you will probably need for this project

Comment: Thanks Mordalthunder, I had a suspicion that php/mysql will be the most needed, javascript too. Thanks a lot.